# Visual studio breakpoint conditional on the stack state

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

Visual studio can print call stack when breakpoint hit, and can stop when conditions are met, is there any way to combine that and stop when function is called from another selected one, and ignore all other calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is with a macro. Right click your breakpoint, choose "When Hit..", select "Run a macro", and point it to a macro that goes something like:

```
 Sub ContinueUnlessCalledFromRightContext()
    For Each frame As EnvDTE.StackFrame In DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames
        If (frame.FunctionName.Contains("SomeOtherMethodsName") Then Exit Function
    Next

    DTE.Debugger.Go() ` we weren't called from the right context so continue execution.
End Sub
```

The above is half psuedo code; I didn't actually test it, but should work with some minor edits.

Note that this will be slow as hell if the breakpoint is hit a lot of times, because running macros from breakpoints is inherently **very** slow.

BTW, If you were asking about .NET / C# it would've been a lot simpler, you could've just made a conditional breakpoint on

```
new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString().Contains("SomeOtherMethodsName")
```

...and be done with it.

Comment: Note from the future: [macros do not exist in current versions of Visual Studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8410838-085b-4647-8c42-e31b669c9f11/macros-in-visual-studio-11-developer-preview?forum=vsx).

I'm open to any suggestions for doing what OP asked in VS2013 and later.

Comment: Visual studio has removed the feature of macro now. Is there any way to achieve similar breakpoint condition for c++ in latest visual studio?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure but you might be able to with either Filtering or Conditions, though it might be easier to just put the breakpoint on the calling process instead

This is a good resource: [Mastering Debugging in Visual Studio 2010 - A Beginner's Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Comment: setting breakpoint on caller is not convenient in my case, I will have to set several breakpoints, and also I want to condition on more then one stack level.